# Symfony 3 one file app and get doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Symfony 3.3, Doctrine 2 one file app(micro kernel) I would like to know if I can use entity menager in AppKernel class.

index.php

```
...

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    use MicroKernelTrait;

    public function registerBundles()
    {
        return [
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle()
        ];
    }

    protected function configureContainer(ContainerBuilder $c, LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
        $c->loadFromExtension(
            'framework', [
                ...
            ],
            'doctrine', [
                ...
                ]
            ]
        );
    }

    protected function configureRoutes(RouteCollectionBuilder $routes)
    {
        $routes->add('/test', 'kernel:testAction', 'test');
    }

    public function testAction()
    {
        $em = $this->container->get('doctrine');

        $response = new Response(
            '<h1>TEST</h2>',
            Response::HTTP_OK,
            ['content-type' => 'text/html']
        );

        return $response;
    }

}

$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

I want to use entity menager in testAction but i don't know how register doctrine as service. I should use configureContainer method?  Anyone can help?

Comment: Have you tried $entityManager = $container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');

Comment: unfortunately `You have requested a non-existent service "doctrine.orm.entity_manager".'`

Comment: Just for kicks, try var_dump($this->container->getServiceIds()); and see if there is anything doctrine related listed.  I have not used the micro kernel but I would have expected there to be a default entity manager created.  I assume you have some sort of config file where you defined database name and credentials being loaded.

Comment: As I thought there is not service releted with doctrine. First i must register doctrine but i don't know how.

Comment: I poked around a bit but did not find anything specific except for https://github.com/CawaKharkov/symfony-micro/blob/master/app/MicroKernel.php Which uses the classic symfony application config files for configuration.  But do let us know if you get it working.

Comment: This solution worked I did so before but is not single file app. When we separate controller and extends by Controller class `$this->getDoctrine()->getMenager()` works perfect.

Comment: There is my example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45012075/symfony-3-micro-kernel-and-orm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I thought the problem was in `configureContainer()` method. For doctrine we need to use again `loadFromExtension()` method. After that we can see doctrine in container.

```
protected function configureContainer(ContainerBuilder $c, LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
         $c->loadFromExtension('framework', [
               'secret' => 'S0ME_SECRET'
         ]);

         $c->loadFromExtension('doctrine', [
                'dbal' => [
                  'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
                  'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                  'port' => null,
                  'dbname' => 'dbname',
                  'user' => 'root',
                  'password' => '',
                  'charset' => 'UTF8'
               ],
               'orm' => [
                  'auto_generate_proxy_classes' => false,
                  'auto_mapping' => true,
                  ...
               ]
         ]);
    }
```